# Umbraco not rendering IE box shadows

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9, umbraco

I am looking at a fix for a website - I have applied a `box-shadow` to a div. This renders perfectly in:

1. Safari, Firefox, Chrome.
2. The SAME CSS renders perfectly in IE when displayed via ASP.NET razor views.
3. The CSS that works in the above .NET, doesn't render via Umbraco.

I am using a separate stylesheet for IE (8.0+) and using:

```
box-shadow: 5px 5px 0px #000
```

in the main stylesheet (for all other browsers) I am using:

```
box-shadow: 0px 40px 100px 2px #000;
```

neither work for IE and I am stumped now.

IE makes me want to drink bleach - anybody have any ideas where I am going wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is IE running in compatibility view mode perchance?

Comment: It usually has a "broken page" icon if it is? I cannot see that. I would say no.

Comment: Just to confirm, box-shadow is only supported for ie9+. you are testing it in ie9 or higher, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does indeed have to do with IE compatibility. Remove this line from your html:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

The line above forces newer versions of Internet Explorer to render the page as IE8 would, by default. See MSDN's [Specifying legacy document modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Douglas Ludlow my friend - you are a genius! That made an IMMEDIATE impact on the site and with a few minor tweaks - it looks SO MUCH better!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the link to your css is relative or something, it's got absolutely nothing to do with umbraco - you have full control over the html. Perhaps paste a link to your website or your html code.

also for cross browser drop shadows you need something like this

```
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #444;
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #444;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #444;
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#444444')";
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#444444');
```

Comment: few things, this - 
`<!-- Internet Explorer fixes -->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/ie-only-stylesheet.css" />
<![endif]--> 
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <!--<![endif]--> 
<!-- Internet Explorer fixes -->`

is between your <head> and <body> tags - very invalid html.
get rid of that second part - '<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html...'
and put first part (link to stylesheet) in the <head> element.

Comment: I've shifted this up (stupid mistake!) and made the changes you suggested!  Thank you!